# Alternativa a método desaparecido en la última versión de librerías Boost asio

Tags: c++

Hace algunos años, escribí un cliente de correo electrónico utilizando la biblioteca asio de Boost.

Hay una clase virtual **ICON** con tres subclases.

**POP3conN** para comunicaciones planas POP3

**POP3conS** para comunicaciones POP3 seguras

**SMTPconN** para comunicaciones SMTP planas

**SMTPconS** para comunicaciones SMTP seguras

**ICON** tiene un miembro

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_
```

y dos procedimientos virtuales, definidos en cada subclase:

```
void SMTPconN::run () {socket_.get_io_service().run(); }
void SMTPconN::reset () {socket_.get_io_service().reset(); }
```

La aplicación funcionó bien hasta boost_1_63_0. Pero cuando intento actualizar a la versión boot_1_70_0, el compilador MS V Studio 2015, genera un error en ambas definiciones:

```
la clase "boost :: asio :: ssl :: stream <boost :: asio :: ip :: tcp :: socket>" no tiene ningún miembro "get_io_service".
```

Puesto que pretendo hacer los mínimos cambios en lo que es una gran cantidad de código y lógica compleja: ¿hay algún atajo a ese método desaparecido de la última versión de asio?

Comment: Has probado en Google a buscar el changelog de esa librería? Tal vez le hayan cambiado el nombre solamente.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Había puesto la misma pregunta en el portal de la versión inglesa de Stackoverlow y me he enterado de que primero fue "deprecated"  luego totalmente desaparecida.  Según parece, ha habido una profunda reestructuración de esta librería, para adaptarla al nuevo estándar de C++